# is vs. are confusion? singular action, plural subject

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Is buying smart electronics worth the price? 
This is the title of an article I am trying to write. Buying is one action,  but electronics is plural. What if I said, "Is *it* worth the price to buy smart electronics?"

Are buying smart electronics worth the price? sounds better I think

Comment: _Buying smart electronics_, a gerund clause, is the subject. Clauses are always singular. So _Buying smart electronics **is** worth the price._

Answer (score 0):

"Are" is incorrect in your example. Your original construction is grammatically correct.

For greater clarity and simplicity, you might say, "Are smart electronics worth the price?" The act of buying is implied by price, so "buying" is a bit redundant in your original headline.